# How to print the characters in the next line for a <td> tag with fixed layout?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Whenever I tried to add more characters in a `<td>` tag, the table expands according to the size. I use `table-layout:fixed;` and `overflow:scroll;` to overcome this but some characters are missing. I need to have the characters to be printed in the next line inside the `<td>` tag.

```
    .styletable {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    width:97.9%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border:1px solid #000000;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}.styletable table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
         table-layout:fixed;

}.styletable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.styletable table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.styletable table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
}.styletable tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}.styletable tr:hover td{

}
.styletable tr:nth-child(odd){ 
    background-color:#e5e5e5; 
}
.styletable tr:nth-child(even){ 
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.styletable td{
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
     overflow:inherit;

    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}.styletable tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.styletable tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.styletable tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.styletable tr:first-child td{
        background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #cccccc), color-stop(1, #b2b2b2) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#cccccc", endColorstr="#b2b2b2");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#cccccc,b2b2b2);

    background-color:#cccccc;
    border:0px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
}
.styletable tr:first-child:hover td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #cccccc), color-stop(1, #b2b2b2) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#cccccc", endColorstr="#b2b2b2");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#cccccc,b2b2b2);

    background-color:#cccccc;
}
.styletable tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.styletable tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="styletable" >
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                Title 1
            </td>
            <td >
                Title 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Title 3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1Row1
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                Row 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                Row 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                Row 3
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 3
            </td>
            <td>
                Row 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: make `overflow-y:scroll` for td

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix the width with either a width or max-width element on css

```
td{
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

for a specific td, use an ID or CLASS and edit it that way

```
.td, #td {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what happens if the character excludes the max-width if there is no space betwee them